# Can Sql Server generate a unique 13 digit number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to generate a unique 13 digit number.

Can Sql Server generate this number for me somehow if I create a table with the 13 digit number as a primary key?

**Update**

I want the number to look like a random number, so not an autoincrementing number.

It has to be 13 digits, and it shouldn't be auto-incrementing, and it should be unique.  The number shouldn't have many zero's in it but it can contain numbers from 0-9.

**This number should look like a credit card number, so no trailing zeros.**

Comment: Why specifically a 13 digit number? Does it have to be only 13 digits or a max of 13 digits?

Comment: How about an IDENTITY column starting with 10000000000?

Comment: Do you want a function to create the ID or do you want something like an auto-increment id which is always a 13 digit number? Please you need to explain yourself better: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @YanireRomero updated my question, hope it clears things up.

Comment: How about using `newid()`?

Comment: Or 6789234567895. Use auto increment but set the Identity to start at some random 13 digit number. Then increment by 1 each time.

Comment: Does 42 count as a 13-digit number? It's the same as 0000000000042? How many is "too many" zeroes?

Comment: @zoff no trailing zeros.  it should look like a randonly generated number, and they generally don't have so many zeros.

Comment: Then what you want is not numbers but a 13-character string made up of 13 random digits 0 - 9 where no more than x of them can be zero. I suggest you write a function to generate this string.

Comment: Why? 1,000,000,000,000 is just as likely as 5,129,486,732,182 if this process is truly random.

Comment: @JohnBarça Yes but the chances of generating a random number with 12 out of 13 of its digits being 0 is highly unlikely, that is what I was getting at.

Comment: @publicstatic. True, the chance is 1/(9*10^13) I think, the same as for any 13 digit number that is truly randomly chosen -- very small indeed. Have you ever seen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford's_law. Not applicable here, but quite interesting when thinking about what randomness looks like in nature. Sadly, the OP has ruined the fun and doesn't want 12 zeros in a row anyway.

Comment: @JohnBarça I am the OP :)

Comment: Was there any resolution to this question?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to have an identity column on the table that auto-increments.  Then, define your value based on this.  A simple way would be:

```
create table t (
    tId int identity(1, 1) not null,
    . . .
    myId cast(rand(tId)*10000000000000 as varchar(13))
)
```

This shows it as a computed column.  Of course, you can assign the value when each row is created.  This is not guaranteed to produce different results, but it is highly, highly unlikely that you would see a collision.

The following is an alternative is also not guaranteed, but might work:

```
create table t (
    tId varchar(13) default cast(cast(rand(checksum(getdate())*10000000000000 as bigint) as varchar(13)
    . . .
)
```

EDIT:

The chance of a collision is a bit higher than I expected -- my intuition on 13-digit hash codes is, I guess, not what it should be.

In any case, there are two sources of collisions.  The first is the random number generator producing the same value.  To handle that, just make the assumption that the random number generator in conjunction with `checksum()` really is random.  So, the question is:  What is the chance of two random numbers less than 10,000,000,000,000 being the same value? I'll let interested parties search the web for a formula to calculate this.

If you generate 1,000 numbers.  Then the probability is basically 0% that any two would be the same.  That is, you are safe for the first 1000 numbers, if you assume they are distinct.  Here is a summary:

```
       1,000             0.0000%
      10,000             0.0005%
     100,000             0.0500%
   1,000,000             4.8771%
  10,000,000            99.3262%
```

Up to a few hundred thousand values, you are probably pretty safe.  When you get into the millions -- even the low millions -- the chance of collision increases substantially.

At some point, if you want lots and lots of unique values, you are going to have to create a table that contains the unique values and a process for choosing a value not in the table.

As John Barça points out:  Do not use this method for cat photos on Facebook.

Comment: The change of collision depends on how big the table is. There are only 9*10^13 numbers that are 13 digits long. If this were unique IDs for cat photos on Facebook, you would run out in weeks :-)

Comment: @JohnBarça . . . I edited the answer.  I can't get a good answer on the number of cat photos uploaded to Facebook.  I did find a reference to 300,000,000 photos per day.  If we assumed that 0.1% of them could be classified as "cat photos" (which for some people would seem a tremendous lower estimate), then you are correct. A duplicate 13-digit-cat-photo code would likely appear within two or three weeks.

Comment: This is essentially the birthday problem -- people generally underestimate the likelihood of collisions. Amazing what cats and dogs have done for extreme engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Guid (select newid() ) & parse it... remove the { and the '-' & do a length of 13 select on it.

Comment: Guid is not all numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I use a similar method to generate random/unique table names in a reporting system.  It might do the trick for you.  Just adjust the multiplier to impact the final integer length.

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT,RAND()*10000000000000)
```

As a table...

```
CREATE TABLE #test (testID INT,
                    UniqueID AS CONVERT(BIGINT,RAND()*10000000000000))

INSERT INTO #test (testID)
SELECT 1

SELECT * FROM #TEST

DROP TABLE #test
```

Just insert a value into testID (can be 1 every time) and a new UniqueID will generate.  You should have a primary key on any production table though.

NB:  While the chances of a duplicate ever happening are very small, it could still happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CEILING(RAND()*9999999999999)
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: insomuch as I executed it 1000 times and it generated 1000 13-digit numbers yeah.  There is no way to 'guarantee' that it will always be unique without storing the number in a table and doing a comparison to implement it.

Comment: If rand were to return 0.00001, for example, how many digits long would you expect the answer to be once rounded to nearest int?

Comment: AH!  Well I guess I'll take my -1.  I was right thinking that CEILING() did what it does but I was mistaken about what RAND() generates.

Comment: The -1 didn't come from me, btw.

Answer (score -2):

something like this might work:

```
use [chamomile]; 
go 
if object_id(N'[utility].[table_01]', N'U') is not null 
  drop table [utility].[table_01]; 
go 
if object_id(N'[utility].[generate_random_sequence]', N'FN') is not null 
  drop function [utility].[generate_random_sequence]; 
go 
/* 
  select [utility].[generate_random_sequence] (rand()); 
*/ 
create function [utility].[generate_random_sequence] ( 
  @random [float]) 
returns [bigint] 
as 
  begin 
      declare @return [bigint] = ceiling(@random * 9999999999999); 
      while @return > 9999999999999 
             or @return < 1000000000000 
        set @return = ceiling(@random * 9999999999999); 
      return @return; 
  end; 
go 
if object_id(N'[utility].[table_01]', N'U') is not null 
  drop table [utility].[table_01]; 
go 
create table [utility].[table_01] ( 
  [my_id] as [utility].[generate_random_sequence] (rand()) 
  , [flower] [sysname] 
  ); 
go 
insert into [utility].[table_01] 
            ([flower]) 
values      (N'rose'); 
select * 
from   [utility].[table_01];
```

Comment: This post is not editable by us due to the plethora of unrelated HTML tags. Please type the SQL as *plaintext*.